# How to use REMOVE feature in NSIS script?

Tags: nsis

I have written nsis script for creating exe file.I have included REPAIR and REMOVE feature in my script.By default i have checked REPAIR Radio button.If the user clicks remove button it will remove the already installed file using following command

```
Function Remove
Exec "$INSTDIR\uninstall.exe"
Quit
FunctionEnd
```

If the user click the remove button it will open the un install window and the user click the uninstall button then only the un install operation will be proceeded.
|Is there any way without asking user input we'll do the remove operation if the user select the remove option?

Comment: What does this have to do with a batch file?

Comment: The NSIS uninstaller is a GUI application, it does not have a console window. cmd.exe for example IS a console application...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Exec '"$INSTDIR\uninstall.exe" /S'
```

You can read more about the command line options [in the manual](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter3.html#3.2.2).

Comment: Thnaks.if use /S option it wont work.It will ask the user input once the user select the remove option.sorry now i have changed title

Comment: What kind of input is it asking for?

Comment: Exec '"$INSTDIR\uninstaller.exe" /S _?=$INSTDIR' if i give this its working fine.thanks

Comment: ?= is really for uninstaller in $temp but you can use it without a temporary copy if you want...